# xxxx could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out)

Tags: nginx, dns, openresty

When invoking other services through HTTP in my app,  parsing DNS is occurring every time. At the beginning, parsing DNS was normal and there was no timeout, but after a while, parsing DNS timeouts became more and more. Take out the timeout domain names separately, and use the 'dig' command to parse in the Linux environment, they are all normal. In my nginx.conf file, resolver_timeout 60s (default 30s), resolver 8.8.8.8. My app is deployed with openresty.How do I check?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?